# Tomcat HA Cluster Setup with NGINX

Tags: tomcat, nginx, load-balancing, tomcat8

I am able to setup a simple tomcat cluster (Node A and Node B) with the tomcat version `apache-tomcat-8.5.8` and `mod_cluster` as the HTTP load balancer. I want to replace mod_cluster with NGINX as the load balancer and want to enable session replication for disaster recovery in case of a tomcat node going down. The OS Version used for the above environment is `CENTOS 7.6`

The tomcat cluster (Node A and Node B) with session replication and the nginx as a reverse proxy (round robin method).

when both nodes (A and B) are running the nginx need to relay the requests via round robin.

1. Request 1=> Node A
2. Request 2=> Node B
3. Request 3=> Node A

If my Node B goes down for some reason i want the session to be replicated and transferred to Node A all the time till my Node B is up and running as part of the cluster

1. 1st request => Node A
2. 2nd request => Node A
3. 3rd request => Node A

Any valuable suggestions on how to achieve the above scenario in a NGINX backed load balancer instead of using mod_cluster in a tomcat cluster based environment